# TFS 2013: Adding a new build agent on a different machine

Tags: tfs

For my TFS 2013 server on machine "A" with one build controller configured, I am trying to add another build agent that's located on another machine "B". the new build agent on machine "B" should be controlled by the same build controller of machine "A". TFS 2013 on machine "B" is installed.

To accomplish this, in Team Foundation Administration Console of machine "A" under "Build Configuration", I use the function "New Agent..." to add a new agent.

Problem is that I cannot change the "Computer Name" because it is geyed out. How can I add the agent of machine "B"?

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install team build (from the TFS installation disk) on the other server.  Then only configure the Team Build section.  When you get to the creation of the controller/agent, only select agent, from there you'll be able to select the other controller (A).

Cheers,
ET

Comment: Thank you Etienne. On machine "B", a full TFS installation (with its own controller/agent/build service) is already installed. It seems to me that the only way to configure the team build service is during the installation process of TFS. 
Can I still register this existing agent of machine "B" to the controler on machine "A" without re-installing TFS?

Comment: I uninstalled TFS completely on machine "B", started a new installation of TFS and chose only the Team Build module. Now I can join this server to an existing build controller of another machine "A". Thanks Etienne.

Comment: Your welcome.  You could have only unsetup the components by running the tfsconfig setup /uninstall:TeamBuild from the tools directory on the server without uninstalling and reinstall TFS.  But it worked for you so great.  Glad I could help.